# Unable to open specific posts on WP Dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, wp-editor

I have this weird problem in the last couple of days where it takes ~5 minutes to completely open some posts on WordPress wp-admin dashboard.

Please hear me out carefully.
1   This is happening only with 1 person in the team. Not an issue for others in the team (same role, same posts)
2   I have tried different browsers, different machines. I even shared my credentials with my editor and he faced the exact same issue.
3   We have disabled Gutenberg and using classic editor. No issues while using Gutenberg (but that's not really an option). The page freezes for approx 5 minutes on opening and eventually loads completely.
4   It's mostly happening for "some" of my own posts already published (it's a multi-authored blog), but I can't be 100% sure since it's all so random.

Here's what all we have tried till now;
1   Tried using Query monitor. Nothing untoward found.
2   Tried activating redis cache. Didn't help.
3   Tried changing my role from Editor to Admin. Didn't help.
4   Deactivated 5-6 recently installed plugins. No luck.

Note: I’ve already asked this question previously, but unfortunately did not receive a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that post no longer shows the comments for some reason.

Here’s what I see-

Attached below are two screenshots: first image is what appears in the Network tab on Chrome. Second is what the editor sees on the console.

[image: this is what I see in the network tab (on Chrome)]

[image: and this is what the console looks like when I click on a post that takes time to load]